# Cannot find Skype in Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, skype

I am in need of Skype but, when I upgraded my system to ubuntu, I found that the Skype is not available in Ubuntu Software Center. Even if I download the package from the Skype the Ubuntu Software Center does not allow to install it.

Its too bad that Ubuntu does not support very popular software Skype.

Comment: what was the format of the skype file you downloaded?If it was **.deb** file, then run `sudo dpkg -i filename.deb`

Comment: Skype is not part of the Ubuntu distribution (including the software centre) because it does not conform to the requirements of the Ubuntu Charter. If you want to know why see here: [SkypeEthics](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeEthics).  But you can install it as the answers below show.

Answer (score 8):

You can find more information on Skype at:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Skype

Meanwhile to get `skype`, you can use the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ $(lsb_release -sc) partner"
```

This command will add the Canonical Partner PPA to your system.
Then use this command to install `skype`

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install skype
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download it and install with next commands:

```
cd ~/Desktop

wget http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb

sudo dpkg -i skype-ubuntu-precise_4.2.0.11-1_i386.deb
```

After you can remove skype from desktop or keep it for next time(after re-installing of Ubuntu).
If the secound command doesn't work you can download skype anytime from skype site : http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/

Comment: A PPA is generally better than a .deb because then updates can be installed just like any package from the usual Ubuntu repositories, such as Nautilus. A .deb is harder to upgrade, and should be a later resort.

Comment: It's right, but Microsoft don't develop skype for Linux, the last update has been made because MS add options to log with MS accounts, MS think just about windows users (

Comment: It's just good practice to use a PPA, so users don't automatically look for a .deb.

Stupid M$.

Comment: I still like the PPA and Application Updater, but: why 2 answers with the same solution???